# Use JSF with embedded Jetty in a non-maven eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, embedded-jetty, buildpath

I want to use JSF in a embedded standalone Jetty webserver application. I cannot figure out what the right jars for the Eclipse build-path must be to get this working.

I think I'm almost there but get an error:

```
WARNING: /home.xhtml @14,49 value="#{helloBean.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'helloBean' resolved to null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /home.xhtml @14,49 value="#{helloBean.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'helloBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'helloBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:45)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:34)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
    ... 43 more
```

The full sample application can be downloaded from here: [JettyWebServer.zip](https://www.timewriter.nl/media/downloads/jsf/JettyWebServer.zip)
. 
Can somebody guide me to the right jars for running JSF in a embbeded Jetty application?

Comment: Please use a build tool, any build tool (maven, gradle, ant+ivy, grape, leiningen, buildr, bazel, or even purl).  Let any of those build tools manage the list of dependencies you have, and this error is likely to just go away.  (as it screams of bad/conflicting dependency choices).  Asking people to load a project in a very specific IDE just to help you isn't the best choice of question on Stackoverflow.  You can improve this question by editing it and showing your dependency list (in text, not an image). Oh, and versions of each jar are important.

Comment: Did you get it working? I have same problem. I believe its cus jetty isn't scanning the jar with the beans. Looking at AnnotationConfiguration it only looks at classes/jars under the web-inf folder.